# what is mvn -T6 option mean?

Tags: maven, command-line, command-line-arguments

I was asked to run this command `mvn -U clean install -T6 -DskipTests` , I would like to understand what -T6 flag stands for in this maven command, can someone help me on this. Please ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: `mvn --help`?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I could find only `-T` option which say ```Thread count, for instance 2.0C where C is core multiplied``` so does this mean 6*2 -> 12 core processing 

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-embedder/cli.html Yes..